# Remove file extension from full path url Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I'm trying to set up an HTML poster image from some videos URL using Javascript, I can get the full path to the file using `"+ element +"` but I can't remove the extension at the end.
I tried a few ways but they all generate errors.

`"+ element +"` will generate this result `img/holidays/4ofjuly2.mp4`

I need to remove on `poster="img/holidays/4ofjuly2.mp4"` `.mp4` to add `.jpg`

I tried .replace(/.[^/.]+$/, "")

and .split('.').slice(0, -1).join('.')

```
function createImagesTag(data){
    var imagesdata = JSON.parse(data);
    images=imagesdata;
    var imagesTag="";
    var a=0;
    imagesdata.forEach(element => {
        if(a==0){
            imagesTag+="<video  muted preload='none' poster='"+ element +"' width='80%' height='40%' id='images_"+a+"' onclick='changeSelected("+ a +")' class='imagescards' <source src='"+ element +"#t=1.5'type='video/mp4' style='border: 3px solid red;'></video><br />"
        }
        else{
            imagesTag+="<video muted preload='none' poster='"+ element +"' width='80%' height='40%' id='images_"+a+"' onclick='changeSelected("+ a +")' class='imagescards' <source src='"+ element +"#t=1.5' type='video/mp4'></video><br />"
        }
      a++;
    });

    document.getElementById("images").innerHTML = imagesTag;

}
```

Comment: "_I tried a few ways..._" - like what? show us your attempt and explain how it doesn't work. Try these: [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring), [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably looking for [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring).
Check the code below, and if you want more information about `reduce,` [check this link from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
function createImagesTag(data){
    const images = JSON.parse(data);
    const imageList = images.reduce((acc, el, index) => {
    const srcWithoutSuffix = el.substring(0, el.length - 4);
      if(index === 0) {
          acc+=`<video  muted preload='none' poster='${srcWithoutSuffix}'' width='80%' height='40%' id='images_"+a+"' onclick='changeSelected(0)' class='imagescards' <source src='${el}'#t=1.5'type='video/mp4' style='border: 3px solid red;'></video><br />`;
          return acc;
      }
       
      acc+=`<video muted preload='none' poster='${srcWithoutSuffix}' width='80%' height='40%' id='images_"+a+"' onclick='changeSelected(${index})' class='imagescards' <source src='${el}'#t=1.5' type='video/mp4'></video><br />`
      return acc;
    }, '');

    const imagesHTML = imageList.substr(0, imageList.length - 4);
    document.getElementById("images").innerHTML = imagesHTML;

}
```

Comment: By using  substring globally I will jeopardize src='${el}'  I need to find a way to replace just poster=""

Comment: @robotron Edited my comment, this should solve your problem

Comment: Itay Elgazar You are the MAN!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the syntax for `<video>` tag, please check the format.

```
<video>
      <source src="">
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

The JS funcktion replace make a good job for this usecase.

```js
const poster = "img/holidays/4ofjuly2.mp4";
const result = poster.replace(/mp4/g, "jpg");
console.log(result)
```